# Delete default value of an input text on button submit

Tags: html

I need to know what I can do in order to delete default value of an input text if user do not fill the field with information. Right now my form display "eg: Ipod, Iphone" when search bar displays. Code example:

```
<input type="text" value="eg: Ipod, Iphone" name="Product" id="Product"
onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'eg: Ipod, Iphone';}"
onfocus="if (this.value == 'eg: Ipod, Iphone') {this.value = '';}" />
<button class="submit" title="Post" type="submit"><span>Submit</span></button>
```

my idea is to display that information - eg: Ipod, Iphone - but if someone press submit with no new information in that textbox the information passed change to Ipod or Iphone and not eg: Ipod, Iphone all together. thanks in advance.

aaaa

Comment: You'll need php to do this.

Comment: Do you want to empty the input boxes if there is no new value inserted by the user ?

Comment: You could use the `placeholder` attribute, **live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/j24jv/1/

Comment: its inside a form in c#, probably I could use jquery but I would like to know if its possible using directly html input tag attributes.. brgds!

Comment: @SheikhHeera yes!, or another value rather than eg: Ipod, Iphone. brgds

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I checked and it seems that placeholder only work with html5 browsers...brgds

Comment: @sebastian_h, then you need some `javascript` code.

Comment: @SheikhHeera ok. i will check for examples...

Comment: @sebastian_h For legacy browsers, you could just use a shim. Check out the section "Web Forms : input placeholder" [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, use html attribute `placeholder`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="eg: Ipod, Iphone" />
```

For the older browsers that does not support this attribute there are some jquery plugins that can handle this. We use [jquery-watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) for that. It only requires you to set the `class="watermark"` on the input and include the script file.

Comment: Not sure if I follow you - I just mentioned a script.